# How to perform operations on kstreams with null keys?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream object like this:

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 1, "name": "john", "age": 26, "updated_at": 1525774480752}
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 2, "name": "jane", "age": 24, "updated_at": 1525774480784}
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 3, "name": "julia", "age": 25, "updated_at": 1525774480827}
```

When i tried to perform the map operation:

```
KStream<String, mysql> locationsStream = pgsql_users.map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<String, mysql>(k.toString(), new mysql ((Integer) v.get("id"), (String) v.get("name").toString(), (Integer) v.get("age")) ));
```

i'm getting an exception as:

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 1, "name": "john", "age": 26, "updated_at": 1525774480752}
```

> Exception in thread
>   "test-app-0d15a00c-51dc-4c1a-8293-82f47fc7ef90-StreamThread-1"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.aail.kafka_stream.lambda$main$0(kafka_stream.java:86)     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.process(AssignedTasks.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:317)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:942)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:822)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)

I thought i'm getting this because the key is null. Can some one help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `k.toString()`, but `k` is null.

You might want to use either `k` as-is, `null` again in the new key, or `String.valueOf(k)` if you actually want the word `"null"` (not recommend, as that sends all messages to a single partition)

Also, since keys are null, you can just set `byte[]` as the key object for the stream. There's no need to use a deserializer